# how to set mysql stored procedures for update with variables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am looking to automate a procedure I am handling manually now. So, I am new to stored procedures and the code below is not working.

It stops when it outputs the first set of variables of the SELECT statement. It does not do the UPDATE and does not continue with the WHILE loop. No errors are reported.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ins_die_1()

BEGIN

    DECLARE v_yr INT;
    DECLARE v_col CHAR(10);
    DECLARE v_base INT;
    DECLARE v_factor INT;
    DECLARE v_cf INT;
    DECLARE v_fuel CHAR(10);

    SET v_yr :=1;
    SET v_col := '';
    SET v_base := 2860;
    SET v_factor := 1;
    SET v_cf := 5;
    SET v_fuel := 'diesel';

    WHILE v_yr <= 5 DO
        SET v_col := CONCAT('ins_yr',v_yr);
        SELECT v_col, v_base, v_factor, v_fuel, v_cf;

        UPDATE ct_insurance 
            SET v_col = (v_base + 1254 + (v_factor * .0032 * price )) 
            WHERE fuel = v_fuel 
                AND CF=v_cf 
                AND price * v_factor < 162000 
                AND version_id = 1746;

        SET v_yr := v_yr+1;

        IF v_yr = 2 THEN SET v_factor := .8;
        ELSE SET v_factor := v_factor - 0.1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE; 

END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I know that there is the IN construct, whereby I should enter the variables manually when calling the procedures, but that seems like an awkward solution and certainly not very efficient.

In case you wonder I have many variables, it's because this is a test procedure. Once it works, hopefully, I will expand it.

Also, I am looking for a mySql solution only, ie, no php involved.

Comment: Is there a column named `v_col` in the `ct_insurance` table? Or are you trying to set a column named `ins_yr2015` by concatenating the year to a string?

Comment: If you want to use a calculated column name, you have to use dynamic SQL: put the `UPDATE` statement in a string, then use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE`.

Comment: @Barmar, The columns on the table are named ins_yr1, ins_yr2, .... ins_yr5. So, I am trying to use the variable v_col as being the name of that column and loop through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column names in the `UPDATE` statement are taken literally, variables don't substitute there. You can do it using dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE ct_insurance 
        SET ', v_col, ' = (v_base + 1254 + (v_factor * .0032 * price )) 
        WHERE fuel = v_fuel 
            AND CF=v_cf 
            AND price * v_factor < 162000 
            AND version_id = 1746');
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

However, you can't access procedure local variables from prepared statements (see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/local-variable-scope.html)) so you need to use user-defined `@` variables.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ins_die_1()

BEGIN

    DECLARE v_yr INT;
    DECLARE v_col CHAR(10);

    SET v_yr :=1;
    SET v_col := '';
    SET @v_base := 2860;
    SET @v_factor := 1;
    SET @v_cf := 5;
    SET @v_fuel := 'diesel';

    SELECT v_col, @v_base, @v_factor, @v_fuel, @v_cf;

    WHILE v_yr <= 5 DO
        SET v_col := CONCAT('ins_yr',v_yr);

        SET @sql = CONCAT('UPDATE ct_insurance 
                SET ', v_col, ' = (@v_base + 1254 + (@v_factor * .0032 * price )) 
                WHERE fuel = @v_fuel 
                    AND CF = @v_cf 
                    AND price * @v_factor < 162000 
                    AND version_id = 1746');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
        EXECUTE stmt;

        SET v_yr := v_yr+1;

        IF v_yr = 2 THEN SET v_factor := .8;
        ELSE SET v_factor := v_factor - 0.1;
        END IF;
    END WHILE; 

END//
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. That did not seem to work though. This was meant to replace the UPDATE block, on the original code, right? It is still stopping at the SELECT statement, without updating the target line on the table.

Comment: What is that `SELECT` supposed to do? It's not selecting from anything.

Comment: It  was just meant to output the variables for checking. Though I do not think it does any harm. I can just take it out.

Comment: I don't think it should be a problem. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Well, actually, if I take out the SELECT statement, it gives a syntax error on the UPDATE string.

Comment: I left out the `=` after `, v_col,`. Try it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77918/discussion-between-bernarda-and-barmar).